# React-Redux add class on element based on comparing two values

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to add a class to table row based on the previous value and present value.If the current value is more than previous value i need to add `crypt-up` and less `crypt-down` className. But is there any easy way to compare current state value and previous state value.As the reducers mutate the store, so how can i compare them?

```
const marketcap = this.props.marketcap.map((coin, i) => (
        <tr key={coin.CoinInfo.Id}>
            <th>{i+1}</th>
            <td className="text-left font-weight-bold"><img src={url+coin.CoinInfo.ImageUrl} className="pr-1 crypt-market-cap-logo" width="20"/>{coin.CoinInfo.FullName}</td>
            <td className="crypt-up"><b>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.MKTCAP}</b></td>
            <td>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE}</td>
            <td>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.TOTALVOLUME24HTO}</td>
            <td>{coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCT24HOUR}%</td>
            <td className="pt-3"><img src={charturl + coin.CoinInfo.Name + charturllast} alt=""/></td>
        </tr>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

**ComponentDidUpdate** will help you, this method accepts prevProps and prevState as parameters, so you can compare prev props with new one like this:

```
state = {
  className: 'crypt-up',
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const className = prevProps.value > this.props.value ? 'crypt-up' : 'crypt-down';

  this.setState({ className });
}
```